# When using a Vue component multiple times in a single page application is the javascript loaded multiple times?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When using a Vue component multiple times in a single page application is the javascript loaded multiple times and do the methods within the script get called multiple times for a single method call?

IE if I use a component 3 times, and when i call method a, will that be called 3 times or just once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component's [lifecycle callbacks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) are invoked in each component instance. If, for example, the `created()` callback contained a `console.log('hello world')`, and you've added three of those components to the `document`, you would see three logs in the console (one from each instance).

On the other hand, event listeners (such as button-click handlers) would only be invoked in the instance from which the event occurred. Say, your component contained a button that had a `click`-event handler calling `console.log()`. Clicking the `button` in one component triggers the handler only in that component, and not other instances of the component.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mok1l3onqp)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example, its appreciated. I do have another question, which is probably off topic but... Can components access functions from an external file?

Comment: No problem. Yes, they can.